# grep something with xargs and find

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

bash guru ;) I'm trying to improve some string in bash which grep specific keyword's matches in specific files. It looks like that:

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -print0 | xargs -0 grep "\*ModelName\:"
```

which works very fast for me! In 20 times faster than this one:

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'grep "\*ModelName\:" {}'
```

But the problem is that in the first script I'm getting the following lines:

```
/<path>/hp/hp-laserjet_m9040_mfp-ps.ppd:*ModelName: "HP LaserJet M9040 M9050 MFP"
```

but desired result is just

```
*ModelName: "HP LaserJet M9040 M9050 MFP"
```

(as in the second script). How can I achieve it?

P.S.: I'm using `find` for flexibility and future improvements of the script.

Comment: I do not understand why you put an intervening `bash` in your second command.

Comment: Even without calling intervening bash explicitly it will work the same slow: find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} grep "\*ModelName\:" {}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-h` option to `grep` suppress filenames from the output.

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h "\*ModelName\:"
```

If your `grep` does not provide `-h` the use `cat`:

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | grep "\*ModelName\:"
```

Also, for your information, `find` provides the `-exec` option which would render `xargs` unnecessary had you wanted to pursue your second option:

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -exec grep grep "\*ModelName\:" '{}' \;
```

Comment: he was talking about speed also. the -exec will make it run slower, but it does solve the file name issue

Comment: Which filename issues could be arised if I use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0`? Which problems `find -exec` solves which can't `find ... -print0 | xargs -0`? Maybe my code is error-prone?

Comment: And yes, my first example was used `find -exec` which was dramatically slower... it took 23 seconds vs 0.3 seconds now. That's why I've decided to rewrite it.

Answer (score 5):

No need for `find`:

```
grep -rh --include "*.ppd" "\*ModelName\:"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of find altogether (in bash):

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -h "\*ModelName\:" /<path>/hp/**.[pP][pP][dD]
```

Might be a bit slower if you have a *huge* directory tree (which I doubt in your case).

- Pro: only one process launched!
- Con: the future improvement you mentioned might be more difficult to implement.

In this case, you'd better use:

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -exec grep -h "\*ModelName\:" {} +
```

(observe the `+` at the end: only one `grep` will be launched).

Answer (score 0):

Think of your output line

```
/<path>/hp/hp-laserjet_m9040_mfp-ps.ppd:*ModelName: "HP LaserJet M9040 M9050 MFP"
```

as a record of three fields separated by a colon. If you think of your output line this way, then you want to extract the third field as your final answer. If you don't know anything about **awk**, you should know at least how to print a column of output data using a specific column separator, as I am showing you below:

```
find /<path>/hp -iname '*.ppd' -print0 | xargs -0 grep "\*ModelName\:" | awk -F:'{ print $3}'
```

The other thing you should know about **awk** is how to sum up (and occasionally, take the average) of the numbers in a specific column of output data, but that's another story for another day :)

The advantage of appending the **awk** command to your command chain is that the you are building on and taking advantage of the fast performance of your optimized command chain :)

In your case, the answer is **grep** with **xargs** and **find** and **awk** :)